# How to get element whose parents child is element x? PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, css, dom

So for example I have a HTML tree like this:

---

```html
<section class="product">
  <div>
    <div class="p-image">
         <img alt="Product name" src="path/to/image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="p-content">
      <h3>Product name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="p-info">
      <div class="new-price">
        <span>400 €</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

So I want to get the content of span element whose parent (div) has a child element (img) with a specific alt attribute. I know how to select an element by its attributes, but I haven't found any solution to selecting an element by it's parent's child.

I hope my explanation was understandable.
Thank you.

Comment: what is that? can you draft a sample HTML markup instead? or why not put the HTML markup in question instead

Comment: @Ghost I added a sample HTML markup now and removed the mess.

Comment: this should be easy using xpath, but in simple-html-dom, you'll need to iterate those children

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery you could use `$(selector).parent()` to get element's parent and `$(img alt="x")` to get the img tag with alt attribute that is equal to `x`

Comment: I know how to get the parent of a element and img tag with alt attribute.But I need to select a span element whose parent div has a child img tag with alt attribute.